# E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, package-management, apache2, software-sources

When I tried to install apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04, I got the following error message:

```
root@Final-Gitsetup-Developers:~# apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libapache2-mpm-itk libapache2-mpm-itk:i386

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

Results of `apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2 $3}' | sort -u`

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/trusty/universe  
http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/wily/mysql-5.6  
http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/wily/mysql-apt-config  
http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/wily/mysql-tools
```

Comment: Check 'Software & Updates' to ensure that in the 'Ubuntu Software' tab, that the 'main' and 'universe' sections are checked, and that in the 'Updates' tab that security and recommended updates are checked.  Then run `sudo apt-get update` and re-try installing Apache2

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks for reply, i have issue in ubuntu server , not in  computer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the software sources in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file that have the string `wily` (Ubuntu 15.10) in them are conflicting with your Ubuntu 14.04 software sources and preventing you from installing apache2. To fix this, preface each line that has the strings `wily` or `xenial` in it by a `#` character in order to turn it into a comment.

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with nano text editor. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 14.04 looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner    
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Every line in the above standard sources.list file has the string `trusty` in it because you are using Ubuntu 14.04. Adding repositories of other Ubuntu releases such as 15.10 or 16.04 to your Ubuntu 14.04 software sources is very bad package management.

<sub>**Nano editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Update the list of available software and install apache2.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install apache2
```

Comment: thanks for answer , but still same result as here : http://prntscr.com/i75fsi

Comment: thanks for update, i tried `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa` to remove all PPAs & tried `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get install apache2`  but still same result.....

Comment: sorry for that, okay i deleted  `sources.list.d` folder from `/etc/apt` , then did `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get install apache2`, still i am getting same error.....

Comment: please check :  http://prntscr.com/i761hq

Comment: i done as your update, http://prntscr.com/i76e4d still getting same error .....

Comment: Don't comment out the lines that have the string `trusty` in them. You need the trusty software sources if you are running Ubuntu 14.04. Leave the lines that contain either `wily` or `xenial` commented out by being prefaced with a `#` character. `wily` and `xenial` software sources are not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: sorry for late reply , i uncommented lines which have word `trusty` , then tried `sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install apache2  ` still got same issue....

Comment: Take a look at te standard sources.list file in the answer and check if you have all the required `trusty` lines in your sources.list file. `main` is the repository that contains apache2. You need a line like this: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main` or this `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse`

Comment: one thing i learned from you is : `we should never give up` , Thanks....